# spring MVC helloworld application shows CannotLoadBeanClassException

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am a novice to spring MVC.I am follwoing a tutorial from the bellow link:
[Spring Hello World](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/02/08/spring-mvc-tutorial-with-eclipse-and-tomcat.html)

While running the application on tomcat server it shows following exception,I guess it is related to the controller class file path,but can't solve it:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet SpringMVCTutorial threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController] for bean with name '/helloworld.htm' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringMVCTutorial-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1266)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1335)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:901)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:652)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:600)
```

Comment: and here is my servlet code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean name="/helloworld.htm" class="java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController"/>
</beans>

Comment: The package of your class is not `java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller`. It's probably `com.springmvctutorial.web.controller`. You should learn about package and class names before using Spring MVC. Also, if your tutorial uses XML files to configure Spring, and declares controllers in the XML file, it's completely outdated.

Answer (score 1):

You put wrong class path at  `SpringMVCTutorial-servlet.xml`. Use following path

```
<bean name="/helloworld.htm"
     class="com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you class file corresponding to `java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController` is not under classpath.

So two things to check here ;-

1)Class file for HelloWorldController created or not.

2)If yes, folder containing i.e java.com.springmvctutorial.web.controller.HelloWorldController should be under classpath

Ideally package name should start with com.springmvctutorial.. not with java.com.. as per java convention

Comment: but how to add the folder under classpath?